# How to show the multiple markers on maps

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

Can anyone explain how to show multiple markers on google maps in android using the following **JSON** code?

```
[
 {"id":"1","lat":"18.105917","lng":"78.838325","location":" Laxmi Filling Station( Medak Road)","distance":"0"},
 {"id":"3","lat":"18.105952","lng":"78.840366","location":"Fathima Filling Station (Medak Road)","distance":"0.1340667689594937"},
 {"id":"13","lat":"18.093713","lng":"78.843775","location":"Thirumala Thirupathi Filling Station (Ensanpally Road)","distance":"0.9160924683870764"},
 {"id":"12","lat":"18.101497","lng":"78.852353","location":"MS Balaji Filling Station ( Old Busstand)","distance":"0.9706182480093937"}
]
```

**All the errors are solved still marker's is not showing on map**

```
private void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {

// De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String location=jsonObj.getString("location");
    double lat=jsonObj.getDouble("lat");
    double lng=jsonObj.getDouble("lng");
    String id=jsonObj.getString("id");
    Log.e("detailes", lat+" "+lng+" "+location);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(location)
            .snippet(id)
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
    );
}
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far and which codes didn't worked for you?

Comment: json array mismatch exception is the error i'm getting

Comment: I think you make a mistake tring to get arrays for latitude and longitude. Check jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng") and jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").

Comment: do it through google map API.

Comment: Your JSON array has "id", "lat", "lng", "location", and "distance" tags. You are trying to use not existing tags for JSON objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

population key is not present in the json string

```
 private void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
// De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
// Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                    .snippet(jsonObj.getString("location"))
                    .position(new LatLng(
                            jsonObj.getDouble("lat"),
                            jsonObj.getDouble("lng")
                    ))
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: replace population with location, now this will work fine

Comment: i have changed the code, All the errors are solved still marker's are not showing on map

Comment: Check whether you have called this method createMarkersFromJson() only after when your map is ready @RaghavaManchala

Answer (score 1):

- Why you calling **`jsonObj.getInt("population")`** ? It's not present
  in your API .
- You suffering from [**`Type mismatches on lookups`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html).

Please change your code like this way .

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String _id    =jsonObject.getString("id");
        String _lat    =jsonObject.getString("lat");
        String _lng    =jsonObject.getString("lng");

     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title(jsonObject.getString("name"))
    .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObject.getString("distance")))
    .position(new LatLng(_lat,_lng ));  // If problem then convert String to double. Use getDouble() instead of getString()

    }
```

Comment: i have changed the code, All the errors are solved still marker's is not showing on map

Comment: http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/2015/08/display-multiple-markers-map-zoom-level.html